# I have question about component of Github project?

Tags: java, android

I'm newer developer. In the project https://github.com/abdularis/Word-Search-Game have issue. there is no "com.aar.app.wordsearch.di.component.DaggerAppComponent". Author answered "That's should be automatically generated by gradle for dagger2". What is it? How to understand it? I opened it with Android Studio, what I do wrong?

Comment: I could open and run the project using Android Studio without any trouble. Make sure that you have a valid internet connection so that the gradle imports the missing file when necessary.

Comment: Let me write an answer for this.

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For cloning project from the terminal.**

**Step 1:** Click this button:

[image]

Clone or download button

**Step 2:** Copy the link.
https://github.com/abdularis/Word-Search-Game.git

**Step 3:** Open the terminal, make sure you are in the folder where you want to clone the project.

enter command:

```
git clone https://github.com/abdularis/Word-Search-Game.git.
```

**Step 4:** after Android Studio builds your project. Click on 
**Build** -> **Rebuild**

when you rebuild your **DaggerAppComponent** will be Generated.

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio, go to the files -> New -> Project from Version Control -> Git. Check the following image.

[image]

Then paste the URL for cloning as follows.

[image]

Then wait for Android Studio to load the program and sync with gradle to download necessary dependencies. Make sure that you have a working internet connection while you do that. Hope that helps!